Transfer access from an envelope to a user - Docusign - 2024 - python
To Transfer access from an envelope to a user in Docusign, I use this code:
        data = json.dumps({"carbonCopyOriginalOwner": False,
                           "envelopeBulkTransferTypeId": "1",
                           "envelopeIds": [envelope_id],
                           "toUserId": to_user_id
                           })

        headers = {
            'Accept': "application/json",
            'Content-Type': "application/json",
            'Authorization': f'Bearer {self.token}'
        }
        url = self.key_vault[self.place]['url'].replace("/users", "")
        envelope_url = "/envelopes/transfer"
        response_request = requests.post(url=url + envelope_url, headers=headers, data=data)

And I get this error:
{
"errorCode": "API_RESTRICTED",
"message": "The API function is restricted and not available for general use."
}
I saw that this problem is recurring, is there any way to succeed in this request?

The error suggests docusign doesn' want you to use that API. Maybe this is a support question for them instead of a question for stack overflow.

I’m voting to close this question because it's basically in the hands of dokusign.

At the time I'm posting this (Aug 2024) this particular endpoint of the eSignature REST API (the one that has /envelopes/transfer) is not actually a public endpoint. The error you're getting is expected as this endpoint is restricted to authorized IK (integration Keys) only.
Following your post I'm asking the team to consider making this endpoint public. I don't have a timeline or a guarantee yet this will happen, but I will update this thread as I know more. I hope this endpoint will become public later this year.
For now, you can use transfer rules, which allows you to specify common rules about how to transfer envelopes, but not actually initiate the transfer from the API.

Hello, thank you very much for the answer.
And how do I request this authorization? I tried on an account that already went live, but also without success.

I'm not sure if there's such a process. You can try to contact Docusign Developer Support
